# Root Archos 101 xs running Android 4.1.1

Tags: rooting, archos-101

I just got an Archos 101 xs Tablet from a friend of mine who has asked me to root it. I'ev had it a whole week and can't figure out a proper way to do so. I have tried searching for one-click tools and other more complex solutions like downgrading, then rooting and then install an already rooted OS. but none of it has worked.

How can I root this device?

Comment: Sorry typing mistake: 4.1.1

Comment: do you try this for 4.1.2? : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2165673 - if you can update to this version, maybe can rooted.

Comment: also : http://www.arctablet.com/blog/featured/archos-101-xs-easy-root-method/ -said : `it will not work with latest Android 4.1 Jelly Bean. If you are running an Android 4.1 Jelly Bean firmware, you will need to downgrade`

Comment: okay thx... I already tried to downgrade the Tablet. There was only one problem: I didn't find any firmware suitable for the Archos 101 xs. Where can I get that from? (The links on the websites you wrote are not available anymore...) :'(

Comment: [ARCHOS 101 XS firmware update 4.1.2](http://www.arctablet.com/blog/forum/archos-101-xs/archos-101-xs-firmware-update-4-1-2-just-released-20130218/)

Comment: I tried both solutions now, but it didn't work. When downgrading i tried your image (tablet brought up the error that the firmware was for another tab) and also searched other images (which came up with the same error).             I just don't know what to do anymore... =P      PLS help if you have any ace in the hole... ;)